# Create stream of numbers that only have certain prime factors

Tags: filter, stream, scheme

I  want to take the infinite stream of numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 ... and filter it so that only numbers that have the prime factors of 7 and 13 are in it. (i.e. 7, 13, 49, 91, 169, 343, ...)

I have the following function started but I'm mixed up on how to properly filter out numbers with only these specific prime factors.

```
(define function
    (stream-filter
        (lambda (x)
            (or
                (= (/ x 7) 1)
                (= (/ x 13) 1)
                )
            )
        numbers
        )
    )
```

Where stream-filter is the same function from SICP.

Comment: am i missing something or can you just do moudlo 7 or modulo 13 on the number?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea: find the prime factors of the number and check if there are factors other than `7` and `13`:

```
(define (factor number)
  (let loop ((divisor 2) (number number))
    (cond ((> (* divisor divisor) number) (list number))
          ((zero? (modulo number divisor))
           (cons divisor (loop divisor (/ number divisor))))
          (else (loop (add1 divisor) number)))))

(stream-filter
 (lambda (x)
   (null? 
    (filter (lambda (e) (not (or (= e 7) (= e 13))))
            (factor x))))
 numbers)
```